# How to use Hoare Logic to Prove this Assertion

Tags: formal-methods, software-verification, hoare-logic

Given [this assertion](http://fsl.cs.illinois.edu/images/6/61/CS522-Fall-2009-11-Hoare-Logic.pdf) in Hoare Logic:

\begin{align}
&\mathbf{\{p >= 0\}}\\
&s = 0 ; n = 1 ;\\
&\mathtt{while}\ (n <= p)\ \{\\
&\quad s = s + n ;\\
&\quad n = n + 1\\
&\}\\
&\mathbf{\{s == p * (p + 1) / 2\}}
\end{align}

How to prove this using the rules of Hoare Logic. I am not sure where to really begin, I only currently understand (most) of the meaning of the [axioms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/92438/understanding-hoare-logic-axioms), but not what is required for a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a question of chaining/glueing the axioms between them.

Let's start from the end:

$$\mathbf{\{s == p * (p + 1) / 2\}}$$

Use the strengthening rule to change the postcondition to

$$\mathbf{\{s == p * (p + 1) / 2 \wedge p == n \wedge p >= 0\}} $$

which is equivalent to

$$\mathbf{\{s == n * (n + 1) / 2 \wedge p == n \wedge p >= 0\}}$$

By the Loop rule in order for the triple:

$$ \mathbf{\{s == n * (n + 1) / 2 \}} \mathtt{while}\ (n <= p)\ \{s = s + n ;
 n = n + 1\} \mathbf{\{s == n * (n + 1) / 2 \wedge p == n \}}
$$

we need to prove that the triple

$$\mathbf{\{s == n * (n + 1) / 2 \}} \{s = s + n ;
 n = n + 1\} \mathbf{\{s == n * (n + 1) / 2\}}$$

is valid.

Let then use the composition to reduce this to proving that the two following triples are valid:

$$\mathbf{\{s == n * (n + 1) / 2 \}} 
\{s = s + n\}
 \mathbf{\{s == (n+1) * (n + 2) / 2\}}$$

and

$$\mathbf{\{s == (n+1) * (n + 2) / 2 \}} 
\{ n = n + 1\}
 \mathbf{\{s == n * (n + 1) / 2\}}$$

The latter one is just an application of the Assignment rule (just replace the occurrences of $n$ by $n+1$ in the postcond to get the precondition).

To prove the first one, we need to apply Strengthening to reduce it to the triple 
$$\mathbf{\{s == n * (n + 1) / 2 \}} 
\{s = s + n\}
 \mathbf{\{s == (n) * (n +1) / 2 + n\}}$$
and then use the Assignment rule trivially.

Okay so now we only need (by Sequence rule) to prove that the triple

$$\mathbf{\{p>=0 \}} s:=0; n:= 1 \mathbf{\{s == n * (n + 1) / 2 \wedge p >= 0\}}$$
which can be done in the same way by splitting with sequence.

Comment: I don't quite understand the part where you substituted value of "n" in "p"